# Adding image in option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a image left of my option when my list opened and I'm using [awesomplete autocomplete plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/) and I'd like to add a picture to show you what I want to do.

I try to add inline css but nothing change

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.awesomplete').on('awesomplete-select', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $sibling = $this.next();
    if ($sibling.attr('id') == 'mylist') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var val = $this.find('input').val();
        var dataLink = $sibling.find('option:contains("' + val + '")').data('link');
        //console.log(dataLink);
        location.href = dataLink;
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.awesomplete>ul {
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin: .2em 0 0;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .8));
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
  .awesomplete>ul {
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4, .2, .5, 1.4);
    transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
  }
  .awesomplete>ul[hidden],
  .awesomplete>ul:empty {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    display: block;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
}


/* Pointer */

.awesomplete>ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.awesomplete>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
}

.awesomplete mark {
  background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
}

.awesomplete li:hover mark {
  background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
}

.awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
  background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<input class="awesomplete dropdown-input" list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at adding an image to the options?

Comment: In option can't add style except background and color proprtey

Comment: http://binnyva.blogspot.in/2006/01/icons-for-select-menu-options-in.html

Try This

Comment: better you can try select2 jquery plugin to achieve this

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: try my code, may be this will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could override the creation of single item putting an image before the label, like:

```
var awesomplete = new Awesomplete(input, {
   item: myItemFunc
});;

function myItemFunc(text, input){
    //return the html to render an item
}
```

See following for a complete example:

```js
var imgList = new Object();
imgList["Ada"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-1.png";
imgList["Java"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-2.png";
imgList["JavaScript"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-3.png";
imgList["Brainfuck"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";
imgList["LOLCODE"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";
imgList["Node.js"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";
imgList["Ruby on Rails"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";

$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("my-input");
  var awesomplete = new Awesomplete(input, {
    item: myItemFunc
  });;
});

function myItemFunc(text, input){
  return Awesomplete.$.create("li", {
    innerHTML: createItem(text,input),
    "aria-selected": "false"
  });
}

function createItem(text, input){
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.style.height = '16px';
  img.src = imgList[text.label];
  var html = img.outerHTML + " " + text.label;
  return html;
}
```

```css
.awesomplete>ul {
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin: .2em 0 0;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .8));
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: none;
  list-style: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
  .awesomplete>ul {
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4, .2, .5, 1.4);
    transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
  }
  .awesomplete>ul[hidden],
  .awesomplete>ul:empty {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    display: block;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
}


/* Pointer */

.awesomplete>ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.awesomplete>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
}

.awesomplete mark {
  background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
}

.awesomplete li:hover mark {
  background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
}

.awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
  background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<input list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: I'm glad you like it

Comment: Even though i'm not the guy who ask this question. But yeah i like it. :D This answer should be accepted :D

Comment: of course I accepted this answer however I'm looking for a way how can do this dynamically :))

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamically"?

Comment: @Alessandro I mean from html not with js :)

Comment: but there is something with wrong this example when I put awesomplete class my input element than your function is not working

Comment: You don't have to add `awesomplete` in html, since it's added via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

try this, here you need to customize awesomplete autocomplete plugin, i have edited that and copied in my code

```js
/*awesomplete.min.js customized and add above code in external file and link that here*/
// Awesomplete - Lea Verou - MIT license
(function(){function h(a){a=Array.isArray(a)?{label:a[0],value:a[1]}:"object"===typeof a&&"label"in a&&"value"in a?a:{label:a,value:a};this.label=a.label||a.value;this.value=a.value}function n(a,b,d){for(var g in b){var f=b[g],c=a.input.getAttribute("data-"+g.toLowerCase());a[g]="number"===typeof f?parseInt(c):!1===f?null!==c:f instanceof Function?null:c;a[g]||0===a[g]||(a[g]=g in d?d[g]:f)}}function c(a,b){return"string"===typeof a?(b||document).querySelector(a):a||null}function k(a,b){return l.call((b||
document).querySelectorAll(a))}function m(){k("input.awesomplete").forEach(function(a){new e(a)})}var e=function(a,b){var d=this;this.input=c(a);this.input.setAttribute("autocomplete","off");this.input.setAttribute("aria-autocomplete","list");b=b||{};n(this,{minChars:2,maxItems:10,autoFirst:!1,data:e.DATA,filter:e.FILTER_CONTAINS,sort:e.SORT_BYLENGTH,item:e.ITEM,replace:e.REPLACE},b);this.index=-1;this.container=c.create("div",{className:"awesomplete",around:a});this.ul=c.create("ul",{hidden:"hidden",
inside:this.container});this.status=c.create("span",{className:"visually-hidden",role:"status","aria-live":"assertive","aria-relevant":"additions",inside:this.container});c.bind(this.input,{input:this.evaluate.bind(this),blur:this.close.bind(this),keydown:function(a){var b=a.keyCode;if(d.opened)if(13===b&&d.selected)a.preventDefault(),d.select();else if(27===b)d.close();else if(38===b||40===b)a.preventDefault(),d[38===b?"previous":"next"]()}});c.bind(this.input.form,{submit:this.close.bind(this)});
c.bind(this.ul,{mousedown:function(a){var b=a.target;if(b!==this){for(;b&&!/li/i.test(b.nodeName);)b=b.parentNode;b&&0===a.button&&(a.preventDefault(),d.select(b,a.target))}}});this.input.hasAttribute("list")?(this.list="#"+this.input.getAttribute("list"),this.input.removeAttribute("list")):this.list=this.input.getAttribute("data-list")||b.list||[];e.all.push(this)};e.prototype={set list(a){if(Array.isArray(a))this._list=a;else if("string"===typeof a&&-1<a.indexOf(","))this._list=a.split(/\s*,\s*/);
else if((a=c(a))&&a.children){var b=[];l.apply(a.children).forEach(function(a){if(!a.disabled){var c=a.textContent.trim(),f=a.value||c;a=a.label||c;""!==f&&b.push({label:a,value:f})}});this._list=b}document.activeElement===this.input&&this.evaluate()},get selected(){return-1<this.index},get opened(){return!this.ul.hasAttribute("hidden")},close:function(){this.ul.setAttribute("hidden","");this.index=-1;c.fire(this.input,"awesomplete-close")},open:function(){this.ul.removeAttribute("hidden");this.autoFirst&&
-1===this.index&&this["goto"](0);c.fire(this.input,"awesomplete-open")},next:function(){this["goto"](this.index<this.ul.children.length-1?this.index+1:-1)},previous:function(){var a=this.ul.children.length;this["goto"](this.selected?this.index-1:a-1)},"goto":function(a){var b=this.ul.children;this.selected&&b[this.index].setAttribute("aria-selected","false");this.index=a;-1<a&&0<b.length&&(b[a].setAttribute("aria-selected","true"),this.status.textContent=b[a].textContent,c.fire(this.input,"awesomplete-highlight",
{text:this.suggestions[this.index]}))},select:function(a,b){a?this.index=c.siblingIndex(a):a=this.ul.children[this.index];if(a){var d=this.suggestions[this.index];c.fire(this.input,"awesomplete-select",{text:d,origin:b||a})&&(this.replace(d),this.close(),c.fire(this.input,"awesomplete-selectcomplete",{text:d}))}},evaluate:function(){var a=this,b=this.input.value;b.length>=this.minChars&&0<this._list.length?(this.index=-1,this.ul.innerHTML="",this.suggestions=this._list.map(function(d){return new h(a.data(d,
b))}).filter(function(d){return a.filter(d,b)}).sort(this.sort).slice(0,this.maxItems),this.suggestions.forEach(function(d){a.ul.appendChild(a.item(d,b))}),0===this.ul.children.length?this.close():this.open()):this.close()}};e.all=[];e.FILTER_CONTAINS=function(a,b){return RegExp(c.regExpEscape(b.trim()),"i").test(a)};e.FILTER_STARTSWITH=function(a,b){return RegExp("^"+c.regExpEscape(b.trim()),"i").test(a)};e.SORT_BYLENGTH=function(a,b){return a.length!==b.length?a.length-b.length:a<b?-1:1};e.ITEM=
function(a,b){var d=""===b?a:a.replace(RegExp(c.regExpEscape(b.trim()),"gi"),"<mark>"+"<img width='15px' src='http://www.download3k.com/icons/Opera-Mini-for-Java-388689.png'/>"+"$&</mark>");return c.create("li",{innerHTML:d,"aria-selected":"false"})};e.REPLACE=function(a){this.input.value=a.value};e.DATA=function(a){return a};Object.defineProperty(h.prototype=Object.create(String.prototype),"length",{get:function(){return this.label.length}});h.prototype.toString=h.prototype.valueOf=function(){return""+this.label};var l=Array.prototype.slice;c.create=function(a,b){var d=document.createElement(a),
g;for(g in b){var f=b[g];"inside"===g?c(f).appendChild(d):"around"===g?(f=c(f),f.parentNode.insertBefore(d,f),d.appendChild(f)):g in d?d[g]=f:d.setAttribute(g,f)}return d};c.bind=function(a,b){if(a)for(var d in b){var c=b[d];d.split(/\s+/).forEach(function(b){a.addEventListener(b,c)})}};c.fire=function(a,b,c){var e=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");e.initEvent(b,!0,!0);for(var f in c)e[f]=c[f];return a.dispatchEvent(e)};c.regExpEscape=function(a){return a.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,"\\$&")};
c.siblingIndex=function(a){for(var b=0;a=a.previousElementSibling;b++);return b};"undefined"!==typeof Document&&("loading"!==document.readyState?m():document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",m));e.$=c;e.$$=k;"undefined"!==typeof self&&(self.Awesomplete=e);"object"===typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=e);return e})();

/*awesomplete.min.js customized and add above code in external file and link that here*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.awesomplete').on('awesomplete-select', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $sibling = $this.next();
    if ($sibling.attr('id') == 'mylist') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var val = $this.find('input').val();
        var dataLink = $sibling.find('option:contains("' + val + '")').data('link');
        //console.log(dataLink);
        location.href = dataLink;
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.awesomplete>ul {
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin: .2em 0 0;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .8));
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: none;
}
ul li{
 list-style:none !important;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
  .awesomplete>ul {
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4, .2, .5, 1.4);
    transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
  }
  .awesomplete>ul[hidden],
  .awesomplete>ul:empty {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    display: block;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
}


/* Pointer */

.awesomplete>ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.awesomplete>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
}

.awesomplete mark {
  background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
}

.awesomplete li:hover mark {
  background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
}

.awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
  background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<input class="awesomplete dropdown-input" list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks it's very well but how shall I change custom image ?