# Added images to the dropdown autocomplete in awesomeplete, submit button then moves down, reset its position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete

Let me start by saying that I was able to find an excellent answer here which I've been able to use to add images to the dropdown menu created by awesomeplete, and that works perfectly. The issue I'm having is that my awesomeplete element is part of a form, so when the dropdown autocomplete displays, the form submit button is pushed down a few lines. Once a value is selected, I would like the submit button to return to its previous position, instead it stays at the lower position on the page.

Here is the code I'm using, which is mostly copied from the first answer at: [Adding image in option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270903/adding-image-in-option) (the only part I have added is the form surrounding the input element and its submit button)

```js
var imgList = new Object();
imgList["Ada"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-1.png";
imgList["Java"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-2.png";
imgList["JavaScript"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-3.png";
imgList["Brainfuck"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";
imgList["LOLCODE"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";
imgList["Node.js"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";
imgList["Ruby on Rails"] = "http://www.maglioccola.com/images/add-4.png";

$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("my-input");
  var awesomplete = new Awesomplete(input, {
    item: myItemFunc
  });;
});

function myItemFunc(text, input){
  return Awesomplete.$.create("li", {
    innerHTML: createItem(text,input),
    "aria-selected": "false"
  });
}

function createItem(text, input){
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.style.height = '16px';
  img.src = imgList[text.label];
  var html = img.outerHTML + " " + text.label;
  return html;
}
```

```css
.awesomplete>ul {
  border-radius: .3em;
  margin: .2em 0 0;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .8));
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: none;
  list-style: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
  .awesomplete>ul {
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4, .2, .5, 1.4);
    transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
  }
  .awesomplete>ul[hidden],
  .awesomplete>ul:empty {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    display: block;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
}


/* Pointer */

.awesomplete>ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.awesomplete>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
}

.awesomplete>ul>li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
}

.awesomplete mark {
  background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
}

.awesomplete li:hover mark {
  background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
}

.awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
  background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<form action="myscript.php" method="POST"><input list="mylist" id="my-input" />
<datalist id="mylist">
 <option data-link="http://www.google.com">Ada</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yahoo.com">Java</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.bing.com">JavaScript</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.yandex.com">Brainfuck</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.php.net">LOLCODE</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.asp.net">Node.js</option>
 <option data-link="http://www.microsoft.net">Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist><br/><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The css code you use for hiding the autocomplete popup is just doing a visual hiding, without removing the object from the layout computations, as with `display:block` the div still takes the required amount of space as if it was visible, pushing all other elements in the layout. The easiest approach would be to use the following:

```
.awesomplete>ul[hidden],
.awesomplete>ul:empty {
    ...
    display: none;
}
```